# Definition of a map as used in map coloring problems.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

I am currently studying topological graph theory, and a number of significant results in this area can be expressed as map coloring questions. Take the four color theorem as an example, a common way of introducing this problem is by posing the question: "What is the smallest number of colors needed to color any map on the plane?".  This is the case with my primary reference text [Graphs Groups and Surfaces](https://www.elsevier.com/books/graphs-groups-and-surfaces/white/978-0-444-87643-0).  However, this text only provides an intuitive definition for a map, relating them to a map of the United States, but not any precisely defined mathematical object.

After a couple days of searching I still haven't found a definition of maps in this sense, and I find it concerning as I do not see how one can rigorously prove the equivalence between this formulation of the theorem and the standard one stating $\chi(S_0)=4$ unless these maps are more precisely defined.

This leads me to ask. Where would I be able to find a reference containing an exact definition of these maps?  I can see intuitively that one should be able to define a map as some sort of partition of either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $S^2$ into connected regions, but I can not quite see what exact qualifications are required to assign colors.

I would like an academic reference to this definition if at all possible, as I may wish to cite it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two standard references for this would be Gross and Tucker "Topological Graph Theory", and Mohar and Thomassen "Graphs on Surfaces. Both are very good, but Gross and Tucker is available as a Dover reprint. (On the other hand Mohar and Thomassen is more up-to-date, but this could be irrelevant for the basics.)

Comment: I will try to find a copy of these, when I do I will comment back with my impressions.  Thank you for the reference.